# Nuxt 3 - Child component not updating on prop value changes by Parent component

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I've a `AppTable` that accepts `data` as prop. This prop is updated by it's parent page, of which this is a part of. `updateFundList()` is getting called and variables are also getting updated, but child component (AppTable) is not updating.

**AppTable.vue**

```html
<template>
  <VueTableLite></VueTableLite>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
 const { config, data } = defineProps({
  data: Array<Record<any, any>>,
  config: Object,
  fundSlot: Boolean,
  slotMode: {
    default: false,
    type: Boolean
  },
});


/// This is not trigging on data change
console.log('updated funds', data);

</script>
```

**Explore.vue**

```html
<template>
  <section class="p-4 px-sm-128">
      div class="fund-filter-grid">
        <h3 class="text-white fw-500 mb-0">Results: {{ pageData.pageSize * pageData.totalPages }} Funds </h3>
        <FundFilters v-if="filters" :filter-obj="filters" @onClear="resetFilters"
                     @onSelect="updateFundList($event)"></FundFilters>
        <AppTable :data="funds" :config="config" :fund-slot="true"></AppTable>
      </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script setup lang='ts'>
...
let funds = reactive<FundDetails[]>([]);
let pageData = reactive<FundPagination | any>(null);

const route = useRoute();
const { data } = await useAsyncData('explore', async () => {
  const { fundsList, pagination } = await getMFsByFilter({page: 1});

  return {fundsList, pagination };
}, { watch: [route]});

funds = data.value!.fundsList;
pageData = data.value!.pagination;


const updateFundList = async ({riskLevels, category, amcId}: Partial<FundFilterReq>) => {
  navigateTo({
    path: route.path,
    query: {
      riskLevels,
      amcId, category
    }
  });

  const res = await getMFsByFilter({riskLevels, category, amcId});
  /// This function is getting called, without any errors. Since funds & pageData is changing here are reactive variables. AppTable should update
  funds = res.fundsList;
  pageData = res.pagination;
};
...
</script>
```